# How would a Uber driver receive a request in real-time (instantaneously) with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-firestore

If I have an app that connect a restaurant to users, how should restaurants receive an order from users as soon as the user request the order? Similarly, how would Uber drivers be notified when riders request a ride?

Adding snapshot listener sounds expensive for Firestore. From what I understand, snapshot listeners should be used when realtime updates are very important but for a limite amount of time, like in a match in a multiplayer game.

To be listening to realtime changes in the Firestore database all day long sounds expensive.

Another option would be a notification. What would be the best option, or which other way would be the most appropriate?

Comment: Did u try childEventListener. ??

Comment: the equivalent to `childEventListener` in Firestore is `addSnapshotListener`

Comment: in that case u can use firebase function, when a new order created to your database u can send a notification. As long as I know childEventListener gets data once and wait for next insertion.

Comment: You're right. both childEventListener and snapshotListener solves it. The problem lies on the fact that on Firestore, listening to changes is financially expensive (while on the Firebase Realtime Database it's the opposite). Firestore is made primarily for one-time queries and storage, and bad for realtime updates, which are things the Realtime Database are good for. So, I could use Firebase Realtime Database with Firestore, but that would add more complexity. I think I will stick with the notifications...

Comment: Firestore is expensive for realtime only for documents that change at a rapid pace. You incur a read cost every time the document changes, whereas the Realtime Database only charges for bandwidth. In general, unless you have documents changing multiple times per second Firestore should be plenty economical for realtime queries.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh Thank you for your comment. It made my day :) So, in my case, would you recommend me to go with realtime updates with Firestore or notifications (FCM)?

Comment: To give more context, the communication would be pretty much telling the restauraunt about the user's request and the restaurante giving 3 updates to the user's app (restaurant accepted the order, order is being prepared, order is on the way) on the order until the whole process (order) finishes.

Comment: That seems like a completely reasonable use case for Firebase. However, if the app might be in the background or closed, you'd probably want to use FCM so that the user is pulled back into the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notifications are most likely the right solution to this use case.

It is difficult to create a mobile app that can correctly keep a Firebase/Firestore listener up and running all the time; mobile OSs like to limit that type of background activity.  (The newer versions of Android are particularly aggressive with background service limits.)

Having your server issue an FCM notification to "wake up" the mobile app for a specific action is reliable and fairly straighforward to implement.